# Style not working in geoserver using rest

Tags: java, rest, geoserver

I am working on geoserver using REST and Java as my programming language. I am trying to apply style to the layer its not working for me.

I have tried with this:

```
workspace=publisher.createWorkspace(workspaceName);
System.out.println("Workspace \"New-Workspace\" created "+workspace);

File sldFile=new File("D:/IDM-Marvin/Geoserver/statestyle.sld");
boolean styleLayer = publisher.publishStyle(sldFile,"staStyle");
System.out.println("State style published "+styleLayer);

String style=reader.getSLD("staStyle");

File stateFile = new File("D:/IDM-Marvin/Geoserver/Test/state.zip");
System.out.println(">>>>>>>file exists"+stateFile.exists());
boolean stateLayer = publisher.publishShp("New-Workspace", "myStore","tl_2014_us_state", stateFile, "EPSG:4326", style);
System.out.println("State layer published "+stateLayer);
```

Please help.

Comment: Please define "not working"